# Best way to access Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image outside xaml.vb?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

```
Imports App1.LoadHandler
Public NotInheritable Class MainPage
Inherits Page
Public Shared mp As New MainPage

    Private Sub MainPage_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded
        lh.Load()
    End Sub
End Class


Imports App1.MainPage
Public Class LoadHandler
Public Shared lh As New LoadHandler

    Public Sub Load()
        AddImageObjectstoList()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddImageObjectstoList()
        dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice1)
        dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice2)
        dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice3)
        dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice4)
        dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice5)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I get the message saying "'App1.MainPage.Private WithEvents imgDice1 As Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image' is not accessible in this context because it is 'Private'." When hovering over dh.imgdice.Add(imgDice1).

In "AddImageObjectstoList()" I can't access imgDice1 - imgDice5 because it is Private. What is the best way to access the Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image controls outside of MainPage.xaml.vb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague but I'm guessing you have `imgDice1` - `imgDice5` declared in `MainPage.xaml`. These are by default private fields. To make them public you need to use `x:FieldModifier="public"`:

```
<Image x:Name="imgDice1" x:FieldModifier="public" />
<Image x:Name="imgDice2" x:FieldModifier="public" />
<Image x:Name="imgDice3" x:FieldModifier="public" />
<Image x:Name="imgDice4" x:FieldModifier="public" />
<Image x:Name="imgDice5" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

This way you'll be able to access them from other classes as well, not only from within `MainPage`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. But you were correct. Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. I thought it would be something as simple as that but couldn't find out how to do it... Thanks again.